# How to detect the display size

Tags: php

I have a PHP script where I use 32px flag icons for language selector. How can I detect the small display to use 24px folder.
Here is my code :

```
<img id="lang" src="./images/flags/32/en.png" />
<img id="lang" src="./images/flags/32/de.png" />
<img id="lang" src="./images/flags/32/en.png" />
```

Comment: Responsive design, look up Bootstrap

Comment: woow this was very helpful, could you put it as answer so I can vote it up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Bootstrap which implemented media queries like:

```
.visible-xs-* Phones (<768px) Visible and Hidden for Desktop (≥1200px)
.visible-lg-* Phones (<768px) Hidden and Visible for Desktop (≥1200px)
```

See more [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes)

Answer (score 0):

Try to look for somethink like this:

http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/

PHP can't detect display size.